# is there a way to read multiple excel tab/sheets from single xlsx to multiple dataframes with each dataframe named with sheet name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I am not good in python please forgive me for this question but I need to create a function which does the following thing:

1. Create multiple data frames from multiple excel tab/sheet present in a single xlsx file and be named on the sheet name.
2. The columns' values should be concatenated and checked if there is no duplicate value.
3. if the concat value has a duplicate then it should be told as yes/No in another column.
4. all the dataframes then should be written into a single workbook as different worksheets inside.
   values inside () are columns for better understanding

example:

sheet1

```
(a) (b) (c) (d)
a1  b1  c1  d1
a2  b2  c2  d2
```

result:

```
(c) (d) (concate) (is duplicate)
c1  d1  c1_d1     no
c2  d2  c2_d2     no
```

sheet2

```
(a) (b) (e) (f)
a3  b3  e1  f1
a4  b4  e1  f1
a5  b5  e2  f2
a6  b6  e4  f4
a7  a8  e4  f5
```

result:

```
(e) (f) (concat) (has duplicate)
e1 f1 e1_f1 yes
e2 f2 e2_f2 no
e4 f4 e4_f4 no
e4 f5 e4_f5 no
```

Comment: You can use `csv` package to do that

Comment: What have you tried so far?, please share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter

def detect_duplicate(group):
    group['is_duplicate'] = ['No'] + ['Yes'] * (len(group) - 1)
    return group

with ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as output:
    for sheet_name, df in pd.read_excel('input.xlsx', sheet_name=None).items():
        df = df.drop(['a', 'b'], axis=1)
        df['concat'] = df.apply(lambda row: '_'.join(row), axis=1)
        df = df.groupby(['concat']).apply(detect_duplicate)
        df = df.drop_duplicates(keep='last', subset=['concat'])
        df.to_excel(output, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
```

Check `output.xlsx` for the output.

Comment: HI Balaji AMbresh,
is there a way that I can create new xlsx workbook with the created dataframes in it

Comment: Updated answer per your ask.

Comment: HI Balaji,
Thanks alot for this just a question why have we used sheet_name=none
also it would be great if you could just brief me about this so that next time I can could learn the working of this

Comment: HI Balaji I have got an error:
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, Timestamp found

Comment: `sheet_name=None` will get `read_excel` to read all sheets within the excel file.

Comment: Could you share the excel sheet where you observed the crash?

Comment: I was able to correct the error by converting the error giving column as str(previous type was datetime) and just to know what does line group['is_duplicate'] = ['No'] + ['Yes'] * (len(group) - 1) do.Thanks again for this

Comment: A list with the same size of the rows that have the same value for `concat` with the 1st value as `No` and the rest of them as `Yes` is created. The list is assigned to the group as a new column

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to read an excel file with multiple sheets, use pandas `ExcelFile` function.

e.g. `df = pd.ExcelFile(filepath)`

And, after reading the excel from the step above, you can read each sheet in a seperate dataframe using the `read_excel` function, e.g.

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(df, 'sheet_name_1')
df2 = pd.read_excel(df, 'sheet_name_2')
```

insert different sheet names and read the sheets in different dataframes.

I didn't understand the latter part of your question please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: this will take alot of time as there are 34 sheets in total.
I want to remove two specific columns from all the sheets which are present in all the sheets.